# conditions in find method

Tags: cakephp, controller, find

I have 3 models,
Mentor, MentorAttrib, Attrib where MentorAttrib is a join table. it lists Mentor.id -> Attrib.id

This is my find

```
$cond = array("Mentor.is_listed"=>1);
$contain_cond = array();
$contain = array(
    'MentorAttrib' => array(
        'fields' => array('MentorAttrib.id' ,'MentorAttrib.attrib_id'),
        'Attrib'
    )
 );

 if(! empty($this->request->data))
 {
      debug($this->request->data);

      //skills
      if(! empty($this->request->data['bookingSkills']))
      {
           $cond = array('MentorAttrib.attrib_id' => $this->request->data['bookingSkills']);
      }
 }

 $this->request->data = $this->Mentor->find('all', array(
      'conditions' => $cond,
      'fields' =>  array('Mentor.id','Mentor.first_name','Mentor.last_name','Mentor.img'),
      'contain' => $contain
 ));
```

I want to filter the result by the skills.

```
[bookingSkills] => Array
    (
        [0] => 2
        [1] => 4
        [2] => 10
    )
```

The error im getting is 
Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'MentorAttrib.attrib_id' in 'where clause'

This is the data set
http://pastebin.com/85uBFEfF

Answer (score 0):

### You need a join

By default, CakePHP will only create joins for hasOne and belongsTo associations - any other type of association generates another query. As such you *cannot* filter results based on a condition from a hasMany or hasAndBelongsToMany association by just injecting conditions and using `contain`.

### Forcing a join

On option to achieve the query you need is to use the `joins` key. As shown in [the docs](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/models/associations-linking-models-together.html#joining-tables) You can also add a join, easily, like so:

```
$options['joins'] = array(
    array('table' => 'mentor_attribs',
        'alias' => 'MentorAttrib',
        'type' => 'LEFT',
        'conditions' => array(
            'Mentor.id = MentorAttrib.mentor_id',
        )
    )
);

$data = $this->Mentor->find('all', $options);
```

This allows the flexibility to generate any kind of query.